How to Prevent Users from Updating to new version of an app from Google Play?
I'm facing an issue where the latest version of my Android app is crashing due to a critical bug. I've already submitted a fix and a new version to the Google Play Store, but it is still under review by Google. In the meantime, I want to prevent users from updating to the current buggy version.
Is there a way to prevent users from updating to a specific version of my app from the Google Play Store, or any workaround to mitigate this issue until the new version is approved by Google? Any guidance or best practices would be greatly appreciated!

Unless you did a staged rollout there is nothing to prevent people from updating

Unfortunately I did a full rollout. So I guess the only option is to wait for the new version to be approved.
